# get custom table data in magento

Tags: magento, grid

I have to show custom table data in grid in super admin and i dont how it will be.
here is my grid file code.

```
public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('customerGrid');
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
        $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }
    protected function _prepareCollection(){
         $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('Advertisement/Advertisementproduct')->getCollection();
        //print_r($collection);die;
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();


    }
```

Comment: is $collection give the results?

Comment: it looks okey. may be you need to try this blog
http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/09/26/admin-part1-series-magento-admin-forms-grids-controllers-tabs/

Comment: Hello @Amit Bera no its not showing anything

Comment: Hello @Punit  i am new in magento so i have no idea about it

Comment: then it issue with magento model classes

Comment: may be its not taking the model class how i can give the correct model path?

Answer (score -3):

```
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$sql = "Select * from the-table-name";
$rows       = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
```

You can iterate $rows and print data. :)